# preventing console errors on fast transition between YouTube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am creating a website where I am embedding a YouTube video on clicking some url's. The wrapper for the video is hidden initially, so I am displaying the wrapper on clicking on a url  and then creating the player.

All is good, except that in case of fast transitions between url's, there are some errors thrown in the console which look like -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<O> has no method 'cueVideoById'
```

Here is the sample code - http://jsfiddle.net/2b6bu7p4/2/

This happens only when I start clicking rapidly on the url's for the first time after page load. If I start on slowly, it works fine.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so a quick fix would be to make sure the player is ready before `cueVideoById` is called

```
function loadVideoOnClick(videoId) {
    console.log('Loading');
    if (player && player.cueVideoById) {
        player.cueVideoById(videoId);
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/2b6bu7p4/5/